# Zabbix create item using item prototype

Tags: json, linux, zabbix

I'm trying to create an item using Zabbix using item prototype and lld detection.
There is an item prototype that receives data from a JSON file using Preprocessing "`JsonPath - $..Name`" in the format:
`["text1","text2"]`
Tell me how to create 2 items with the values "`text1`" and "`text2`", and not 1 item with the value `["text1","text2"]`?
Zabbix 6.4.9